# How to set view to overlay bounds when overlay added to a map?

Tags: leaflet, fitbounds

I'm loading an overlay ('overlay' in the code below) onto a leaflet base map (openstreetmap) and would like that this overlay completely fills the display  window once loaded.

I think I should use getBounds and setView using values gotten through getBounds but didn't manage to make it work.

```
// initialize the map
  var map = L.map('map').setView([48.85, -3], 15);

  // load a tile layer
    L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.de/tiles/osmde/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>',
        minZoom: 3,
        maxZoom: 18,
        subdomains: 'abcd',
        detectRetina : true
    }).addTo(map);    


    //Load overlay

    var overlayOptions = {
            attribution: '...',
            //minZoom: 3,
            maxZoom: 19,
            opacity: 1,
            format: 'image/png',
            detectRetina: true,
            //unloadInvisibleTiles: true,
        };
        overlay = L.tileLayer('https://www.laurentgontier.com/BrehatSHOM/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', overlayOptions).addTo(map);

        //fit map view to overlay bounds
map.fitBounds(overlay.getBounds());
```

So far, the last line supposed to frame the overlay into the display window doesn't seem to work.

Comment: `getBounds()` doesn't make sense on a tile layer - it has no bounds. Can you describe what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks ! I'm overlaying a little map (tile layer) and would like that this map fits into the display window (i.e. code automatically gets map bounds and fits the view to these bounds). Exemple here where the overlay map overflows the viewport where I'd like it to fit in : https://www.laurentgontier.com/Brehat/Brehat.html